# Accessing an iFrame within shadow dom using TestCafe

Tags: iframe, automated-tests, e2e-testing, shadow-dom, testcafe

Is it possible using TestCafe to access an iframe that is contained within a ShadowDom?

I have tried using a combined selector, the same way I can access plain ShadowDOM elements, but can't manage to get the iFrame to work.

The error message that comes up is `1) The iframe in which the test is currently operating does not exist anymore.`

this.iFrame = $(() => document.querySelector('body > div:nth-child(3)').shadowRoot.querySelector('div > iframe'))

Comment: Without more detail it will be difficult for users to assist you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for producing a minimal, complete, reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for using TestCafe. Switching to iframes located in shadow roots is not supported yet. I've created a feature suggestion about it in the TestCafe repository: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3673. You can use it to track our progress in implementing this feature.